# efficient join >100 files

Tags: bash, performance, join, merge

I have a list containing >100 tab-delimited files, containing 5-8 million rows, and 16 columns (always in the same exact order). From each file I need to extract 5 specific columns, including one identifier-column. My final output (using 3 input files as an example) should be 4 files, containing the following columns:

- output1: ID, VAR1
- output2: VAR2.1,VAR2.2,VAR2.3
- output3: VAR3.1,VAR3.2,VAR3.3
- output4: VAR4.1,VAR4.2,VAR4.3

where ".1", ".2", and ".3" indicate that the column originates from the first, second and third input file, respectively.

My problem is that the input files contain partially overlapping IDs and I need to extract the union of these rows (i.e. all IDs that occur at least once in one of the input files). To be more exact, output1 should contain the unions of the "ID"- and "VAR1"-columns of all input files. The row order of the remaining output files should be identical to output1. Finally, rows not present in any given input file should be padded with "NA" in output2, output3 and output4.

I'm using a combination of a while-loop, awk and join to get the job done, but it takes quite some time. I'd like to know whether there's a faster way to get this done, because I have to run the same script over and over with varying input files.

My script so far:

```
ID=1
VAR1=6
VAR2=9
VAR3=12
VAR4=16
while read FILE;do
    sort -k${ID},${ID} < ${FILE} | awk -v ID=${ID} -v VAR1=${VAR1} -v VAR2=${VAR2} -v VAR3=${VAR3} -v VAR4=${VAR4} 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"};{print $ID,$VAR1 > "tmp1";print ${ID},$VAR2 > "tmp2";print ${ID},$VAR3 > "tmp3";print ${ID},$VAR4 > "tmp4"}'
    awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$1;next};{if(($1 in a)==0){print $0 > "tmp5"}}' output1 tmp1
    cat output1 tmp5 > foo && mv foo output1
    join -e "NA" -a1 -a2 -t $'\t' -1 1 -2 1 output2 -o auto tmp2 > bar2 && mv bar2 output2
    join -e "NA" -a1 -a2 -t $'\t' -1 1 -2 1 output3 -o auto tmp3 > bar3 && mv bar2 output3
    join -e "NA" -a1 -a2 -t $'\t' -1 1 -2 1 output4 -o auto tmp4 > bar4 && mv bar2 output4
    rm tmp?
done < files.list
sort -k1,1 output1 > foo && mv foo output1
```

Final remark: I use `cat` for output1 because all values in VAR1 for the same ID are identical across all input files (I've made sure of that when I pre-process my files). So I can just append rows that are not already included to the bottom of output1 and sort the final output-file

Comment: why do you sort?

Comment: good question `NEGR KITAEC` and check the `bar2 && mv bar2 output2` and the next line `bar3 && mv bar2 ...`.

Comment: Is `ouptut` in `cat ouptut1 tmp5 > foo` a mistake in your original script or only here ?

Comment: The first `awk` command uses `ID`, `VAR1`, `VAR2`, `VAR3`, `VAR4` as input variables. When are they filled?

Comment: Where do you get the `ID`? Is that the first column, and `VAR1` the second column?

Comment: I thought `join` needed sorted input files? I further sort output1 in the end because those rows have been appended together using `cat`, which is faster than `join`. I need to use `join` for the other output files because I need to pad rows that are missing in a given input file with "NA"

Comment: @WalterA I've pre-selected tmp5 to contain only the rows that are not already present in output1. And since I know that there's no missing value in any column, I can just append tmp5 to the bottom of output1 and sort later on. I need to use `join` for the other output files because I need to pad rows that are not present in any given input file with "NA". E.g. suppose ID123456 is not present in the second input file, then this ID is still present in output2, and it's value needs to be set to "NA".

Comment: @WalterA I fill the variables at the beginning of my script, which I forgot to add here. I've updated my question to reflect this

Comment: @DonchoGunchev I've tried to set the output of join to be the same as the input (e.g. `join -e "NA" -a1 -a2 -t $'\t' -1 1 -2 1 output2 -o auto tmp2 > output2`), but this sometimes messes up the order of the file. Is there a better way than writting the output to a temporary file and then renaming it?

Comment: When I asked about `ouptut` being a mistake, I meant the spelling. Should be `output`, not `ouptut`.

Comment: @Hill You can not `join X > X` because it will overwrite the output file before fully reading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to figure out where most of the time is lost. You can 'echo "running X"; time ./X` and make sure you are not trying to optimize the fastest part of the script.

You can simply run the three joins in background in parallel `(cmd args ) &` and then `wait` for all of them to finish. If this takes 1 second and the `awk` part before takes 10 minutes then this will not help a lot.

You can also put the `wait` before `cat output 1 tmp5...` and before the final `sort -k1...` line. For this to work you'll have to name the temporary files differently and rename them just before the `join`s. The idea is to generate the input for the three parallel joins for the first file in background, `wait`, then rename the files, run the `join`s in background and generate the next inputs. After the loop is complete just wait the last `join`s to finish. This will help if the `awk` part consumes comparable to the `join`s CPU time.

HTH, you can make even more complex parallel execution scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! It's actually the `sort`-command in the first line inside the while-loop that's taking up most of the time. I thought this would be faster than sorting the separate files before the `join`s, but forgot that I could do those in parallel. I now run the 3 `join`s in parallel where - within each parallel run - the required columns are first extracted and then followed by a `sort`. This has halved the running time of my script